# Java/Groovy double for statement question

Tags: java, groovy

This is a Java/Groovy question, im doing this function to implement in a search mechanism in my website. I have two lists:

```
String [] lista = temp.split() // ignore the temp part
String [] searchLista = search.split() // ignore the search part
```

Basically, the lists are something like this:

```
    lista = {a, b, c, d}
    searchLista= {a, b, a, d}
    boolean test
```

I want to verify if, any element on list 'lista' is the same on 'searchLista'. For that i did the following function:

```
for(int i = 0; i< lista.length-1; i++){

                for(int j = 0; j< searchLista.length-1; j++) {

                    if(lista[i].contains(searchLista[j])){
                        test = true
                        ##
                    }
                }
            }
```

My question is, if this validation is true: 'lista[i].contains(searchLista[j])', boolean variable test becomes true and next i want to jump outside both fors. A simple 'break' in the place of the ##s will do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Are you deliberately missing out the last element of both lists, by the way?)

A normal `break` statement would just exit the inner loop.

If you want to break two levels, there are three common options:

- Make the condition for the outer loop something which you can make false in the body
- Make the whole loop a method, and just return from it
- Use a break with a label

Example of the last option:

```
// Code before loop
outerLoop:
for (...) {
    for (...) {
        if (...) {
            break outerLoop;
        }
    }
}
```

Personally I don't use labels very often - I would rather use the "make the whole double loop a method" option if possible.

Comment: A label is very similar to a `goto`, and we all know that "Go To Statement Considered Harmful" (but also "'Go To Statement Considered Harmful' Considered Harmful", etc) :)

Comment: @Michael: I don't think it's nearly as arbitrary as a goto... but I still prefer simpler approaches.

Comment: "Go To Statement Considered Quite Handy When Used Sparingly and Appropriately" just isn't quite as catchy I guess

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to find out whether the 2 arrays have any elements in common, the Groovyiest way to do this is:

```
boolean haveElementsInCommon(array, otherArray) {
  !array.toList().disjoint(otherArray.toList())
}
```

Here are some tests for the function/method above

```
// create some test data
String[] list1 = [1,2,3,4]
String[] list2 = [5,6,7,8]
String[] list3 = [8,9,10,11]

// test the function works for arrays with nothing in common           
assert !haveElementsInCommon(list1, list2)
// test the function works for arrays with at least one element in common    
assert haveElementsInCommon(list2, list3)
```

You can run the code above in the [Groovy Console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) to verify it works

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No - though the slightly longer answer is "this only affects performance, though, not correctness since `test` will still be `true` once you (eventually) exit the loops".

The reason is that `break` only breaks out of the directly enclosing loop.  In this case, you have doubly-nested loops and want to break out of both of them.  One way to do this, is with a label:

```
OUTER: for(int i = 0; i< lista.length-1; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j< searchLista.length-1; j++) {
      if(lista[i].contains(searchLista[j])){
          test = true
          break OUTER;
      }
   }
}
```

Other alternatives would be to change to condition on the outer loop to `i < l;ista.length - 1 && !test`, or to wrap this all up into a function from which you can simply `return`.

Since it's Groovy however, I'd have thought there'd be a Groovier way to (lazily) calculate the intersection of two sets - at which point you can just test whether the intersection is empty or not (which is what you're really after here).  It's *definitely* clearer to write

```
test = !intersection(lista, searchLista).isEmpty()
```

and this may be no worse in terms of performance too.

Answer (score 0):

a simple break would only break the inner for loop.
but you could do this in a own function and add a return statement at ##.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.intersection(Collection, Collection)` instead. Put each array into a `Set<String>` first.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this with Groovy would be:

```
lista.any { it in searchLista }
```